# Is there a value for the neutrino oscillation ratio $L/E$ (length over energy)?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos

That ratio keeps popping up, yet I have nowhere read an estimated value...

Are scientists at least certain that high-energy neutrinos oscillate less often?

Comment: have a look https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/521871/

Comment: Essential [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/521871/what-is-the-advantage-of-long-baseline-neutrino-accelerators-with-respect-to-sh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are "certain" to the extent scientific facts can be such: There is no plausible hint of experimental doubt, at present.

Even though there is a virtual duplicate provided in the comments, you appear to be in doubt about the neutrino oscillation formula, namely the mutation probability out of a neutrino changing its flavor,
$$ 
 P_{\alpha\rightarrow\beta, \alpha\neq\beta} = \sin^2(2\theta)~~ \sin^2 \left(\frac{\Delta m^2 L}{4E}\right)\,  $$
in customary HEP  natural units, $\hbar=1=c$.

The practical usage, semi-SI units for huge distances [km],  are only partially dimensionalized,
$$P_{\alpha\rightarrow\beta, \alpha\neq\beta} = \sin^2(2\theta)~~ \sin^2 \left( 1.27 \frac{\Delta m^2 L}{E} \frac{\rm [eV^{2}]\,[km]}{\rm [GeV]}\right). $$

Written like this, it means *L* should be in km, *E* in GeV, but
*Δm<sup>2</sup>* in eV<sup>2</sup>, as these are the practical units in the trenches, with the freaky numerical factor picking up the conversion slop. (A purist would invert the dimensions' fraction on the right and remove the brackets, for logical consistency, but I already described what is meant. Check   the reinstated ${1\over 4\hbar c}= 1.27 {GeV\over km~ eV^2}$.)

- So, go to your [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf) and look at "atmospheric" neutrino conversion: For *Δm<sup>2</sup>* ~ 2.5 $10^{-3}$ eV<sup>2</sup>, and a 1 GeV beam, you'd need  500 km for the first outconversion maximum, etc...